# Create symbol label to the table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, attribute-table

I am trying to create the field which contains its symbol label, is there any tool  to do this?

I use ArcMap10.3

[image]

Comment: What did you use to classify the file into 'level_-2 etc'? This should be a value in- or a rule based on a value in the attribute table...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, if you right click the layer and select Properties and select Symbology tab what is the field name under Categories>Unique Values>Value field drop down?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to calculate the field with the field calculator.  You'll need to set the expression to return the ranges that you used to classify the symbology.

For example, if your field holds values like 1 through 1000.  You've broken the range into 5 classes.  So for the first class, the expression would return level_1 by returning 'level_1' for range in 1-250 (field > 0 AND field < 251), then second class return 'level_2' for range in 251-500 (field > 250 AND field < 501), etc.

Here's some documentation on field calculator expressions to explain how to set up your expressions:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm